# Ограничение доступа к каталогам в Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Как с помощью `.htaccess` можно заблокировать доступ к папкам извне. В моём случае к `database`, `views` и `uploads`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в доках [`<Directory> Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)

```
<Directory "path">
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Оно?